# Submit button don't add data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, form-submit

I tried to create a form which will send an email and add data to MySQL data base. For email part because I work on localhost I used formsubmit. All good but there is a conflict. When I press on send only the email is send without any data added to my database. If I delete the action attribute from form data will be added but in this case I can't send any emails. Here is my file:

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

if(!empty($_SESSION["id"]))
{
    $id= $_SESSION["id"];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE id= $id");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
    
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $cui = $_POST['cui'];
    $tip = $_POST['tip'];
    $adresa = $_POST['adresa'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO beneficiari VALUES('','$email','$name','$cui','$tip','$adresa')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$query);

}

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Beneficiari </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexCSS.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="beneficiariCSS.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav">
            <a href="#">Welcome <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></a>
            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            <a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a> 
            <a href="anunt.php">Anunturi</a>
            <a href="view.php">Viz</a>
            <a href="beneficiari.php">Registration</a>
        </div>


    <div class="container">
        <form action="https://formsubmit.co/0e6b51872b4393271dbfa08bb0655fc8" method="POST">
            <h3>Inregistrare</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Denumire institutie" required>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter an valid email" required>
            <input type="text" name="cui" id="cui" placeholder="CUI" required>
            <input type="text" name="tip" id="tip" placeholder="Tipul institutie" required>
            <input type="text" name="adresa" id="adresa" placeholder="Adresa" required>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
            
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood php.
When you submit the form, request will directly go to the formsubmit.co. It won't run your php submit code in this file

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the action from form, and add it after the SQL query, within the if statement as `header`, like so:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $cui = $_POST['cui'];
    $tip = $_POST['tip'];
    $adresa = $_POST['adresa'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO beneficiari VALUES('','$email','$name','$cui','$tip','$adresa')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    header('location: https://formsubmit.co/0e6b51872b4393271dbfa08bb0655fc8');
}
```

I believe this will work.
But whatever you do **make sure you check the input!!** The way you are handling your input right now is very dangerous, and allows users to inject you with SQLs (read up on SQL injections and protection)

Comment: For now I only use this for a personal project and it will never be hosted online. This way don't work, I only get the data in my database using this.

Comment: @DariusMan ok, I've edited it to have a cleaner redirect usage.

Comment: wait, do you need the post data to be sent to the formsubmit.co URL as well?

Comment: this approach is fine. After the sql query execution, need to send the post request in the following way.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php

Comment: Yes, I want to send data from form to fromsbumit.co to get it on my email aswell. @tola